# House auction system

Tags: php, sql

I have a game where you can bid on houses. Its very simple. I have two tables

```
Table: houses

id | name | owner_id
```

and

```
Table: house_auctions

id | house_id | current_bid | bidder | enddate
```

Now If someone wanna bid I just check if subbmitted bid is greater than current_bid. If it is I update current_bid and set bidder to whoever placed bid. Then after a week whoevers ID that is in bidder i update to owner_id in houses table. I don't care to show history of bids. I dont need that.

So while this works good one feature I would like to have is having the user putting a limit. Like he place a bid of 5$ on a house and set his limit to 50$. Then if someone else comes and places a bid of 35$ then I dont want to accept his bid but place 36$ dollar of whoever set limit to 50$.

How should I do this? I realise I need a third table. Could I have some tips on maybe schema? Also Im using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a third table with all bids:

```
Table: house_auction_bids

id | house_auction_id | bid | bidder | date
```

Then you can implement the logic to calculate the bids.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for history, couldn't you just add a column of the second highest maximum bid, and then the current bid column would actually be the maximum bid of the current winner. The displayed current bid doesn't need to be stored, as it would just be the (second highest bid + 1)

Answer (score 0):

I have just thought about this and i would suggest that you add an dataset house_auctions every time a user places a bid. You dont change the existing one, you add a new one.

Then you can select the maximum of current_bid of an house_id and with that you get the current maximum bid.

To achieve the principle of a bid_limit you can just enter the limit as current_bid and then you query the two highest bids for a house, the price the house currently has is the lower price + 1.